# Django runserver gives me syntax error

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

```
python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x03BBC1F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "C:\Users\Kaidi\Desktop\CM2\CM\CM\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from mysite import views

  File "C:\Users\Kaidi\Desktop\CM2\CM\mysite\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions, status

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from rest_framework import generics, mixins, views

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 10, in <module>
    from rest_framework import mixins, views

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 98, in <module>
    class APIView(View):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 103, in APIView
    authentication_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 220, in __getattr__
    val = perform_import(val, attr)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 165, in perform_import
    return [import_from_string(item, setting_name) for item in val]

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 177, in import_from_string
    module = import_module(module_path)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_jwt\authentication.py", line 1, in <module>
    import jwt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jwt\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .jwk import (

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jwt\jwk.py", line 60
    def is_sign_key(self) -> bool:
                          ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 18):

You seem to have installed the JWT package, which is only compatible with Python 3.4+. The rest-framework-jwt app is trying to import that rather than PyJWT which is compatible with 2.7.

Remove that installation with `pip uninstall jwt`. Once removed you'll want to install PyJWT like so:

```
pip install PyJWT
```

Answer (score 1):

Not need to uninstall jwt. Just upgrade your PyJWT

```
pip install PyJWT --upgrade
```