# Error on JWT file using AWS lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, jwt, aws-lambda

I have an error on python JWT package, it used to work fine for me but know I have this issue:

```
START RequestId: b7364861-32ef-11e7-95fd-194d4089f11f Version: $LATEST
Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (jwk.py, line 60)

END RequestId: b7364861-32ef-11e7-95fd-194d4089f11f
REPORT RequestId: b7364861-32ef-11e7-95fd-194d4089f11f  Duration: 0.28 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 18 MB
```

jwk.py is part of the JWT package not part of my code:

```
Line 60 is:

    def is_sign_key(self) -> bool:

From:

class AbstractJWKBase:
def get_kty(self):
 raise NotImplementedError() # pragma: no cover
def get_kid(self):
 raise NotImplementedError() # pragma: no cover
def is_sign_key(self) -> bool:
 raise NotImplementedError() # pragma: no cover
def sign(self, message: bytes, **options) -> bytes:
 raise NotImplementedError() # pragma: no cover
def verify(self, message: bytes, signature: bytes, **options) -> bool:
 raise NotImplementedError() # pragma: no cover
def to_dict(self, public_only=True):
 raise NotImplementedError() # pragma: no cover
@classmethod
 def from_dict(cls, dct):
 raise NotImplementedError() # pragma: no cover
```

I really don't know what is wrong? I used python2 as the environment when installing the package so I don't think it is a version issue, but can't say for sure.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python_jwt

Comment: That's python3 syntax, is the script running as python2?

Comment: @jordanm i guess that's the issue (running 3 code in a 2 env). I'm installing with a python 2 virtual env though. So I'm not sure if the problem is me or them.

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716699/django-runserver-gives-me-syntax-error

Answer (score 1):

JWT needs Python 3 while you are using Python 2.

Suggest you to use PyJWT instead